# Javascript inherit from array and make it global

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object, function-prototypes

The small demo below illustrates my problem:

```
// 1 - Define a global reference to classA
(function() {
    window.classA = new ClassA();
})();

// 2 - ClassA object definition
function ClassA() {
    this.test1 = function() {
        document.write('test1');
    };
}

// 3 - ClassA inherits Array and has a test function
ClassA.prototype = new Array;
ClassA.prototype.test2 = function() {
    document.write(this[0]);
}

// 4 - Test our ClassA
var c = new ClassA();
c.test1();
c.push('test2');
c.test2();

// 5 - Test our global ClassA
classA.test1();
classA.push('test2'); // doesn't work
classA.test2(); // doesn't work
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/SPSW4/

What is the proper way to define a global variable classA (ClassA instance)?

Comment: you mean global as in static? did you consider reordering of your function calls?

Comment: global variable (an instance of ClassA)

Comment: there are no classes in JavaScript and naming a function _class_ makes no sense. This makes it very confusing to read. Please reconsider your naming convention ;)

Comment: simply an example, please pay no attention to the names :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to be binding the global `classA` variable before `ClassA` is fully defined.  I believe you will have more luck if you do it like:

```
// 1 - define ClassA 
window.ClassA = function() {
    this.test1 = function() {
        document.write('test1');
    };
};
ClassA.prototype = new Array;
ClassA.prototype.test2 = function() {
    document.write(this[0]);
}

// 2 - Define a global reference to classA
window.classA = new ClassA();

// 3 - Test our ClassA
var c = new ClassA();
c.test1();
c.push('test2');
c.test2();

// 4 - Test our global ClassA
classA.test1();
classA.push('test2'); // doesn't work
classA.test2(); // doesn't work
```

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/SPSW4/2/

Comment: Close but 'window.classA = new ClassA();' would have an influence on the order of my javascript right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly.  But `window.classA = new ClassA();` just needs to occur *after* you are done configuring  `ClassA`.

Comment: Not exactly true, but mainly.  As you see by my answer, only the prototypes need to come before the assignment.  That is because prototype methods are applied to objects that use the `new` keyword.  Since those methods aren't attached at the time of `... = new ClassA()` the object doesn't see them.

Comment: In my answer I did `ClassA.prototype = Array.prototype;`, but here you do `ClassA.prototype = new Array;`. Is there any diference?

Comment: @Mario - I think the way you did it is better, or at least more closely following commonplace JavaScript coding conventions.  I just kept the code that was being used in the original post, since it seemed to work anyways.  Although if you just set `ClassA.prototype = Array.prototype` then won't adding a new method to `ClassA` also cause that new method to appear in `Array`?  Perhaps using `new Array` avoids that issue?

Comment: @aroth I don’t see the point on avoiding extensions of the Array prototype but your explanation is right. Thanks for letting me know about this ...strange behavior.

Comment: @Mario & @aroth - using `new Array` would provide you with a "sort of" sub-class of `Array`. Using `Array.prototype` will actually just point your new constructor's prototype to `Array.prototype`

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach would be to create the pseudo-sub-classed `Array` constructor within an immediately invoked function expression and then expose the result to an explicit global object.

```
(function( global ) {
    // Declare the ArrayLike constructor
    function ArrayLike() {
        var args = [].slice.call( arguments ), 
            length = args.length, i = 0;

        this.length = length;

        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            this[ i ] = args[ i ];
        }
        return this;
    }
    // Define ArrayLike's prototype by creating a new Array instance
    ArrayLike.prototype = new Array();

    // Define your own proto method
    ArrayLike.prototype.firstChar = function() {
        var ret = [], 
            length = this.length, i = 0;

        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            ret[ i ] = this[ i ][ 0 ];
        }
        return ret;
    };
    // Expose the ArrayLike constructor.
    global.ArrayLike = ArrayLike;
})( this );

var a = new ArrayLike( "alpha", "beta", "gamma" );

console.log( a.push("delta") ) // 4
console.log( a ); // ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"]
console.log( a.firstChar() ); // ["a", "b", "g", "d"]
```

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/rwaldron/gLdkb/

Answer (score 0):

**swap**

```
// 2 - ClassA object definition
function ClassA() {
    this.test1 = function() {
        document.write('test1');
    };
}

// 1 - Define a global reference to classA
(function() {
    window.classA = new ClassA();
})();
```

declaration **before** calling functions in JavaScript, it is a scripting language.

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon on test2 defintion - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// 2 - ClassA object definition
function ClassA() {
    this.test1 = function() {
        document.write('test1');
    };
}


// 3 - ClassA inherits Array and has a test function
ClassA.prototype = new Array;
ClassA.prototype.test2 = function() {
    document.write(this[0]);
}

// 4 - Test our ClassA
var c = new ClassA();
c.test1();
c.push('test2');
c.test2();

// 1 - Define a global reference to classA
window.classA = new ClassA();

// 5 - Test our global ClassA
classA.test1();
classA.push('test2');
classA.test2();
```

Actually there were two problems:
1. Creating object before declaring class
2. Creating object before extending class

Comment: Same as with aroth's solution, this would influence the order of the javascript files. The function call technique should prevent that... but how to put it all together.

Comment: If you have this happening in different files, then you should say so in your question.  Regardless, the solution is still the same.  You just have to do *something* that ensures that you don't try to call `new ClassA()` until *after* `ClassA` is fully defined.  A reasonable way to do this is to move the `window.classA = new ClassA();` part so that it is at the very end of the file that defines `ClassA`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly Zyphrax you can do something like that at each of your files: `if (typeof(classA) === 'undefined') window.classA = new ClassA();`. Ugly but will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Define your class**

```
ClassA = function()
{
    this.test1 = function()
    {
        document.write('test1');
    };
};
```

**Then apply array prototype**

```
ClassA.prototype = Array.prototype;
```

**Then you can extend your class**

```
ClassA.prototype.test2 = function()
{
    document.write(this[0]);
};
```

About the “global reference” part. In the first part of your code your are not making a reference, you are instancing a class which has not been defined yet at that point. There is no need to do that also. What is your point with that part?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the class definition before the call.

   ***Note:** The only thing that really needs to come first is the prototyping, since your code first assigns the class, but never sees the effect of the prototyping, which occurs later.  Your class assignment should come after the prototypes.*
2. You're missing a `;` after the `test2()` definition.

```
// Class Definition
function ClassA() {
   this.test1 = function() { document.write('foo'); };
}
   ClassA.prototype       = new Array();
   ClassA.prototype.test2 = function() { document.write(this[0]); };


// Init
(function() { 
   window.classA = new ClassA(); 
})();

// Method Calls
var c = new ClassA();
    c.test1();
    c.push('bar');
    c.test2();

classA.test1();
classA.push('bar');
classA.test2();
```